# Split after a number of character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, google-maps, split

I'm working with latlon values for YM4R with google maps.  I need to know how to split a string after 10 characters.

Here is an example string "51.5261658-0.0810102" if I know split the string after the 10th character, I would be able to get separate lat lon values.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just split on the `-`?

```
str = "51.5261658-0.0810102"
values = str.split("-")
lat = values[0]
lon = values[1]
```

Here we slice off the first 10 characters

```
str = "51.5261658-0.0810102"

#remove the - if it's there
str.gsub!("-","")
lat = str.slice!(0..9)
lon = str
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Maybe this helps also [http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html) for further problems...

Comment: Well I thought that initially. PRoblem is, not all longitudes have a - which is why I wanted to split it after 10 characters

Comment: Updated. It now removes the "-" and slices off the first 10

Comment: If you get bored click the checkbox next to my answer :P